# Excel: COUNTIF function treats 'less than' character as an operator

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice

Pre-read note: I'm using LibreOffice rather than Excel, but most functions should apply to both.

I'm making a spreadsheet where I have a bunch of data, and for every property (such as # of employees or a name) I need a function that calculates how many rows contain each distinct value.
I already have the distinct values extracted, and now I'm using the following function to calculate how many rows have each value: `=COUNTIF(start:end;value)`. (Note that the semicolon is LibreOffice's way of separating parameters, as opposed to Excel's comma.)

Now, my problem is that I have some rows that can have values such as "< 50". Using the `COUNTIF` function, it seems that the '<' is treated as a 'less than' operator, rather than as a text character. Therefore, if the cell I'm trying to match the column against has the value "< 50", I end up with a value 0 as result of the formula. How can I get the `COUNTIF` to treat the less-than sign as a text character? Or is there another function I should use here?

Comment: The cells don't actually contain double quotes. And as the criteria for the COUNTIF, I directly pass the cell number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel you could use SUMPRODUCT, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((start:end=value)+0)`

The direct comparison using = will do an exact comparison and isn't confused by < or > like COUNTIF

Comment: This works the same with a CountIf, `=COUNTIF(A:A,"=< 50")` would return any cells with exactly `<50`

Comment: Are you using that formula in LibreOffice or Excel? `COUNTIF` doesn't work for me in Excel 2007 - If I put <50 in A1 and use =COUNTIF(A:A,"=< 50") I get the result 0 as Lars suggests - when I use this formula `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="<50")+0)` I get 1 as expected

Comment: I used it in Excel added an answer with screen shot also.

Comment: OK I see where I went wrong, I copied from your comment and it didn't work with a space between < and 5 so I removed that and it worked OK, good call! I assume that Lars tried =COUNTIF(A:A,"<50") which doesn't work......

Comment: I actually need the reference to the cell, not its value. In other words, I tried something like =COUNTIF(A:A,C2). With cell C2 then containing the value "< 50".

Comment: To get that to work as per user2140261's suggestion try =COUNTIF(A:A,"="&C2)

Answer (score 9):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"=< 50")
```

Works for me in Excel 2007

[image]