# Countif for "greater than" operator returns wrong result (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count something that's categorized to 4 values.
Let's say those values are:

> 1. less than or equal to 1
> 2. 1.1 to 2
> 3. 2.1 to 3
> 4. greater than 3

If I have this data inputted in A1-A8 excel cells:

> ≤ 1
>   ≤ 1
>   1.1 to 2
>   1.1 to 2
>   2.1 to 3
>   2.1 to 3
>   > 3
>   > 3

And I collect only the unique values in B1-B4 excel cells:

> ≤ 1
>   1.1 to 2
>   2.1 to 3
>   > 3

All those cells are in "General" format already and have TRUE value in =istext() function

I used countif functions this way:

> =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8;B1)
>   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8;B2)
>   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8;B3)
>   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8;B4)

I expected the result to be:

> 2
>   2
>   2
>   2

As I have two "> 3" in my data

but the actual result returned these values:

> 2
>   2
>   2
>   0

can anybody help me with this?
thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

The countif() is not recognizing the "<=" or ">" while doing its evaluation or the cell A1 is trying to evaluate the "<= 1" and not succeeding.

I suggest using "LT=" or "GT" and then it works:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,"="&B1)
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029970/excel-countif-function-treats-less-than-character-as-an-operator)

Comment: it's the simplest working-solution!
thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

As [Solar Mike says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520804/9290986), this is because `>` is treated as a special comparison for numbers.

To bodge a conversion to text, prepend it with an asterisk in your `COUNTIF`, like this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8; "*" & B4)
```

This **will** look for any text that *ends* in `"> 3"`, so would also pick up things like `"This is > 3"` (but **not** `"Is this > 3?"`, because it has text after the `"3"`)